# Euclidean Space is a Lie Group under Addition

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

I attempt to understand the definition and examples of Lie group supplied by *An Introduction to Manifolds* by Loring Tu (Second Edition, page no. 66). The definition is given below.

[image]

The first example is as follows.

> The Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lie group under addition.

For $\mathbb{R}^n$ to be a Lie group, the multiplication map $\mu: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, \mu(x, y) = x + y$, and the inverse map $i: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n, i(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, need to be $C^{\infty}$. I am convinced that $\mu$ is a $C^{\infty}$ map on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$, but I don't see how the inverse map $i$ is $C^{\infty}$ at $x = 0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. To understand it better, I considered the limiting case where $n = 1$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In that case the inverse map $i$ is not defined at $x = 0 \in \mathbb{R}$.

What am I missing here? How can then $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Lie group under addition?

Comment: The additive inverse of $x$ is $-x$, so the inversion is $i(x)=-x$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I totally missed this point earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to talk about $\frac1x$ when $x\in\Bbb R^n$ and $n>1$. The inversion, in this context, is the map $x\mapsto-x$.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, in your answer, I believe it should be "... when $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $n >1$.".

Comment: I've edited my answer. Thank you.